Why I cannot add new word into WordNet using library "wn_editor" (Python)?
(Python) I am now stucking at editing WordNet lexicons by using "wn_editor". It keeps error like this in every single lexicon (except "odenet"). There are very few documents for me to fix this.
Here is the error image:
To initiate wn and wn_editor
import wn
import wn_editor

Calling the LexiconEditor to edit the chosen lexicon
# own-en is an English WordNet lexicon
editor = LexiconEditor('own-en')

# Create new Synset to add a word
# ERROR here
new_ss = editor.create_synset()

# Add a new word
# ERROR here
new_ss.add_word('newWord')

And this step keeps error (except I use odenet lexicon)
# This is not error
editor = LexiconEditor('odenet')

# Create new Synset to add a word
# Not ERROR anymore
new_ss = editor.create_synset()

# Add a new word
# Not ERROR anymore
new_ss.add_word('newWord')

I currently runs Jupyter Notebook file and on VSCode:

Python = 3.10.11
wn = 0.9.5
wn_editor = 0.5.4

